# Error on naming when using a predefined table/database for CakePHP

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, naming-conventions

I am currently trying out cakePHP to be integrated with my MSSQL database. I have already set up my connection with MSSQL, and currently I am trying to test my connection by selecting all the contents of a certain table in MSSQL. However when I am trying to run my query, this error happens:

> Table tbl_tag__vehicles for model Login was not found in datasource
>   default.

I understand that it is saying that it cannot find the table `"tbl_tag_vehicles"` from the database, but what I placed in my code is this:

> var $name = "TblTag_Vehicle";

I am wondering why it is happening, because the table name in the database is "`TblTag_Vehicle`", but cakePHP is doing something to the string and it converts it to a different name.Is it because of CakePHP's naming standards?And is it possible for me to turn off whatever it is that is converting the table name?

Answer (score 1):

// Dude you cant do anything like turn off name conventions , cakephp wont work in that case.

In model you should write

```
var $name = "TblTagVehicle";
```

AND Give same name to model file LIKE `TblTagVehicle.php`
There should NEVER be underscore in name of model .

Comment: Looks like I have to change my framework to a different one. I'm already using an existing database, so renaming the tables would affect the other application that is using it.

Comment: Yes :) bcoz naming conventions are very imp. for cakephp to work. 
1)Primary key MUST have name `id`.
2)Foreign key must have singular name of table preceded with id like `user_id` for users table.
3)Tables MUST have plural names. with underscores if you think it should have some capital letter like `user_types` -> 
4)If there are more than 2 words ,separate by underscores and make last word plural . like `user_types` here types is made plural not user . And lot more :)

Comment: I see, I was thinking of importing the database to another instance and rename the tables, but the database is large, so running scripts to match both databases would waste a lot of resources, so I guess I'll look into another framework for my application. Thanks.

Comment: @marchemike , by the way how many tables are there in your database?

Comment: Around 200 - 250 tables on the estimate.

Comment: :) then go for other framework , Bcoz in cakephp , you start step1 with Table/their fields ,  naming convention and then you structure your MVC coding .